# How use JKS Keystore in the Spring Security SAML2 context

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-saml, spring-security-saml2

I am in the middle of transferring an old SAML implementation that was written using the Spring Security SAML Extension into the the Spring Security SAML2. I have difficulties with the following bean:

```
<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/ssoKeystore_test.jks" />
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="client123" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="ssokey" value="client123" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="ssokey" />
</bean>
```

Is there any equivalent way in the Spring Security context to configure the key manager?
I want to work exclusively with the Java configuration

Comment: Did you find the way?